# How to get value by Java enum class name and field name

Tags: java

How to get value by Java enum class name and field name?
The sample code is as follows, but I don't know how to pass the enum class as a parameter.

```
public enum ErrorCodes1{
    OK(0),
    NOT_EXIST_USER(1),
    FAIL_TO_SEND_MAIL(2),
    ...
}
public enum ErrorCodes2{
    OK(0),
    NOT_EXIST_USER(1),
    FAIL_TO_SEND_MESSA(2),
    ...
}
public void foo1()
{
    foo2(ErrorCodes1.class, "NOT_EXIST_USER");
    foo2(ErrorCodes2.class, "NOT_EXIST_USER");
}

public void foo2(Enum EnumClass, String EnumText)
{
    int code = xxxx; //I want to get code(1) via EnumText and EnumClass, but I don't know how to do it.
}
```

Comment: what's stopping you from doing `ErrorCodes1.NOT_EXIST_USER.getValue()`? btw, how is the value 0,1,2 exposed in the enum?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option A, simple:** check for the type explicitly.

```
int code;
if (enumClass instanceof ErrorCodes1) {
   code = ((ErrorCodes1) enumClass).valueOf(enumText).ordinal();
} else if (enumClass instanceof ErrorCodes2)
   // repeat
```

This implies you can pass an error object itself, not necessarily its class. Unfortunately, `switch` does not work with Class type.

**Option B, probably overkill:** use Reflection.

```
public void foo2(Class<?> enumClass, String enumText) {
   try{
      Object resultingEnum = enumClass.getMethod("valueOf", String.class).invoke(null, enumText);
      int code = (Integer) resultingEnum.getClass().getMethod("ordinal").invoke(resultingEnum);
      // ...
   } catch (NoSuchMethodException | IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException e ) {
      // ignore: enumClass is not an expected class
   }
}
```

This will suit you in case you have an unlimited number of ErrorCode enums, though it is a barely plausible situation.

Comment: None of these solutions is ideal.  The first is actually just a refactored switch-case block.  These are brittle in the context of enums because the compiler will not help you refactor them when new constants are added.  The second solution is a kind of expensive dynamic dispatch.  So why not just use a dynamic dispatch?  Write an interface that specifies the contract of the desired behavior for the enum classes, and have the enum classes implement it.  Addresses the problems of the 1st solution (the compiler will now help you) and the 2nd (faster, more elegant, easier to read).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the type `Class` as a param of your function `foo2`

```
public static void foo2(Class<?> enumClass, String enumText) {
   int code = -1; // I want to get code(1) via EnumText and EnumClass, but I don't know how to do
                        // it.
    switch (enumClass.getCanonicalName()) {
        case "ErrorCodes2": {
            ErrorCodes1 errorCode = ErrorCodes1.valueOf(enumText);
            code = errorCode.ordinal();
        }
        case "ErrorCodes1": {
            ErrorCodes1 errorCode = ErrorCodes1.valueOf(enumText);
            code = errorCode.ordinal();
        }
    }
    System.out.println(code);
}
```

After that, you can use `valueOf` to instantiate your enum from a string that contains the enum value. I don't think this is the best solution but its works.

PS: The param of a function begins with a lowercase letter.

Comment: ... the irony of using a switch-case block with enum classes for which you are the developer.

Comment: @scottb how can i ameliorate this?